# OutOfMemory Exception on Android

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I'm using in my application an external jar-library, which is working with bitmaps. This causes an out of memory exception in my application. This kind of problem is described in following issue:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8488

Once OOME occurs, an activity crashes, application is still going runing, memory will be free, but the wifi-connection will be lost.

Is there the way to get memory free before activity crashes? Probably, I should say, I have no access to bitmaps, which are using by the library. I also tried to call System.gc() in onPause and onDestroy, but that doesn't help.

Why would be memory free when activity crashes?

What did happen with wi-fi-connection?

Thank you

**upd**

this library is [osmdroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/)

Comment: It'd help if you documented the .jar usage. Maybe you're not calling the API which frees/recycles the bitmaps. Or maybe you're decoding large images at their native resolution and it's just too much.

Comment: This bibliothek is osmdroid, i haven't seen any api which frees / recycles the bitmaps. But I will take another look

Answer (score 1):

Try to extend `Application` class with your own (need to be declared `AndroidManifest.xml`). In those `Application` class there's one method `Application.onLowMemory()` - which has to be called on low memory. You can override this method and try to release unnecessary resources. Probably it will be usefull.

Comment: Ok, but how can i release unnecessary resources of the library (btw., it's osmdroid)?

Comment: @Mur You need to call the `clear` method of your `MapTileCache` instance. I found it easier to make the `MapTileCache` instance a singleton and then call in the body of `onLowMemory` implementation `MapTileCache.getInstance().clear();` @barmaley that's a very right suggestion, thanx.